# SMS Message not sent to Etisalat United Arab Emirates Number

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm trying to send SMS messages to multiple numbers with different providers, I do receive the message an Etisalat Egypt phone number but do not receive it on an Etisalat UAE number.

How can I pass spam filtering for Etisalat UAE numbers on Twilio?

My code is simply:

```
async sendSMSBatch(content, phoneNumbers) {
    return Promise.all(_.map(phoneNumbers, (phoneNumber) => {
      return client.messages
                   .create({
                     body: content,
                     from: messagingServiceSid,
                     to: phoneNumber,
                   });
    }));
  }
```

and I've enabled Advanced Opt-Out. I've even attached

```
To stop receiving SMS reply “b +31 [number] to 7726"

Reply STOP to unsubscribe.
```

to the message itself. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. This is likely not a programming problem, instead I'd reach out to [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) with some message SIDs of messages that didn't arrive and see if they can help.

Comment: Thank you, Phil, I've opened a ticket and waiting for a response.

Answer (score 0):

This is the recommended approach to sending SMS to United Arab Emirates.

United Arab Emirates - Guidelines
https://www.twilio.com/guidelines/ae/sms